# awk sed perl to merge rows based on keyword match

Tags: perl, bash, awk, sed

I've been banging my head head against the wall on this issue due to my limited awk/sed wizardry. I'm happy to use awk,sed,bash,perl, or whatever to accomplish this text manipulation.

I have the following output and would like to merge lines based on a sort of key match:

```
 Node: server1
 Active Server: SECONDARY
 Standby Server: PRIMARY
 Primary 192.168.1.1
 Secondary 192.168.1.2

 Node: server2
 Active Server: PRIMARY
 Standby Server: SECONDARY
 Primary 10.1.1.1
 Secondary 10.1.1.2
```

Desired output:

```
 Node: server1
 Active Server: Secondary 192.168.1.2
 Standby Server: Primary 192.168.1.1

 Node: server2
 Active Server: Primary 10.1.1.1
 Standby Server: Secondary 10.1.1.2
```

So I need the lines to merge based on the words "primary" and "secondary". My first thought was to change "Primary" to "PRIMARY" so it would be easier to match.

My eventual goal is to have this:

```
 server1,Active,192.168.1.2,Standby,192.168.1.1
 server2,Active,10.1.1.1,Standy,10.1.1.2
```

(but I can figure this part out after help merging the rows)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's the tricky part Avinash! That's why I need to match based on the common key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl solution seems to do what you ask. It simply pulls the values into a hash line by line, and dumps the hash contents when all the required values are present.

**Update** I've used `any` from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) in place of `grep` to make the code more legible.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use List::Util 'any';

my @names = qw/ node active standby primary secondary /;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt';

my %server;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  next unless my ($key, $val) = lc($line) =~ /(\w+).*\s+(\S+)/;

  %server = () if $key eq 'server';
  $server{$key} = $val;

  unless ( any { not exists $server{$_} } @names ) {
    printf "%s,Active,%s,Standby,%s\n", @server{'node', $server{active}, $server{standby}};
    %server = ();
  }
}
```

**output**

```
server1,Active,192.168.1.2,Standby,192.168.1.1
server2,Active,10.1.1.1,Standby,10.1.1.2
```

Comment: Fairly self-documenting, although that `grep` line took a bit of working out...Do you need to do `%server = ();` twice though?

Comment: @TomFenech: No, not if the data file is reliable. I'm just insuring against anything strange in there.

Comment: @TomFenech: Would you prefer `if ( @names == grep { exists $server{$_} } @names ) { .. }`?

Comment: I guess the way you're already doing it is less repetitive. It makes sense now I realise that `grep` will return the number of elements in `@names` that are not in `%server`, so when this is `0` the condition is met.

Comment: @user3574338: You're welcome. **Update** I've used `any` from `List::Util` in place of `grep` to make the code more legible (and insignificantly faster).

Answer (score 1):

It is dense and very ugly multi-liner,

```
perl -00 -nE'
  s/ ^(\w+)\s+([\d.]+)\s* / $s{$1}=$2; ""/xmge;
  ($l=$_) =~ s! \s*\w+:\s*|\n !,!xg;
  $l =~ s|\U$_|$s{$_}| for keys %s;
  ($_=$l) =~ s/^,|,$//g;
  say
' file
```

output

```
server1,Active,192.168.1.2,Standby,192.168.1.1
server2,Active,10.1.1.1,Standby,10.1.1.2
```

**Explanation**

```
# -00 => instead of single line read lines into $_ until \n\n+
perl -00 -nE'
  # read and remove 'Primary|Secondary IP' into $s{Primary} = IP
  s/ ^(\w+)\s+([\d.]+)\s* / $s{$1}=$2; ""/xmge;

  # replace 'something:' or new line by ','
  ($l=$_) =~ s! \s*\w+:\s*|\n !,!xg;

  # replace SECONDARY|PRIMARY with actual IP address
  $l =~ s|\U$_|$s{$_}| for keys %s;

  # remove ',' at beginning and end of the string
  ($_=$l) =~ s/^,|,$//g;

  # print result
  say
' file
```

Comment: For the benefit of Perl novices such as myself, could you provide some explanation of what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Or using a one-liner for the intermediate desired solution (final solution to follow):

```
perl -00 -lpe '
     s/ Server: \K(\w+)(?=.*^(\1[^\n]*))/$2/ismg;
     s/\n[^:]+$//;
   ' file.txt
```

Outputs:

```
Node: server1
Active Server: Secondary 192.168.1.2
Standby Server: Primary 192.168.1.1

Node: server2
Active Server: Primary 10.1.1.1
Standby Server: Secondary 10.1.1.2
```

Explanation:

- Switches:

  - `-00`: process input in paragraph mode (separated by double returns)
  - `-l`: enable line ending processing
  - `-p`: assume `"while (<>) { ...; print; }"` loop around program
  - `-e`: evaluate perl code
- Code:

  - Replace all Server values with a matching line that begins with the same key
  - Remove the server list at the bottom.

To get the final solution you want, the following one liner will accomplish that goal.

There are some slight changes from the first solution like using `-n` instead of `-p` because we want to move from two newlines between records to one new line.  However, the regex tools are the same:

```
perl -00 -ne'
    s/ Server: (\w+)(?=.*^\1\s+(\S+))/:$2/ismg;
    s/\n[^:]+$//;
    s/^Node: //;
    s/[\n:]/,/g;
    print "$_\n";
  ' file.txt
```

Outputs:

```
server1,Active,192.168.1.2,Standby,192.168.1.1
server2,Active,10.1.1.1,Standby,10.1.1.2
```

Comment: I think this could benefit from some explanation as there appears to be a lot going on!

Comment: @TomFenech You're probably right.  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Did you test this? As far as I can see there can only be one `$h{primary}` and one `$h{secondary}`, so all the servers will be displayed with the same pair of IP addresses

Comment: @Borodin Yes, I tested.  There can be only one primary and secondary per node, but that's how the OP presented his data.

Comment: @Borodin Changed my implementation method to use lookahead assertions to make it simpler, and so it matches the same method I used for the full solution.

Comment: @Miller: I see where I was confused: I had forgotten that `-00` does paragraph mode. Another little murky corner of Perl!

Comment: @Borodin Yeah, I have to admit, I have some dislike using the `-00` switch along with `-0777` because neither is apparent what's going on based off of `perl --help`.  Yes, they're documented in [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), but that's the third resource a beginner would come to, which is a little annoying.

Comment: @Miller: It's also kinda weird that `-00` is paragraph mode, while `-0` (and, presumably `-000`) set the record separator to `NUL`

Comment: @mpapec Thanks for the correction.  Could also have used `-E` and `say`, but I tend to shy away from that feature for some reason.

Comment: NP, I've only removed switch letter. As for `-E` it doesn't work on ancient `v5.8-`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    $1 == "Active"  {active = tolower($NF); next} 
    $1 == "Standby" {standby = tolower($NF); next} 
    $1 == "Primary" {ip["primary"] = $0; next} 
    $1 == "Secondary" {
        ip["secondary"] = $0
        print "Active Server:",ip[active]
        print "Standby Server:",ip[standby]
        next
    }
    1
'
```

This assumes the "Secondary" line is at the end of a "block".

To achieve your next output:

```
awk -v OFS="," '
    $1 == "Node:"   {node = $NF}
    $1 == "Active"  {active = tolower($NF)} 
    $1 == "Standby" {standby = tolower($NF)} 
    $1 == "Primary" {ip["primary"] = $2} 
    $1 == "Secondary" {
        ip["secondary"] = $2; 
        print node, "Active",ip[active],"Standup",ip[standby]
    }
'
```

---

Responding to jhill's comment:

```
awk -v RS="" -v OFS=, '{
    node = active = standby = ""
    delete ip
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if      ($i == "Node:")     {node=$(++i)}
        else if ($i == "Active")    {active = tolower( $(i+=2) )}
        else if ($i == "Standby")   {standby = tolower( $(i+=2) )}
        else if ($i == "Primary")   {ip["primary"] = $(++i)}
        else if ($i == "Secondary") {ip["secondary"] = $(++i)}
    }
    print node, "Active", ip[active], "Standup", ip[standby]
}'
```

Comment: How about using `RS=""` and a field-counter to slurp pairs until n>NF?  +1 for the clearest code here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Added another option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr` to eliminate spaces, then `sed` to put then back in the right place and use `perl` to get the output you want:

Input file:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ cat file
 Node: server1
 Active Server: SECONDARY
 Standby Server: PRIMARY
 Primary 192.168.1.1
 Secondary 192.168.1.2

 Node: server2
 Active Server: PRIMARY
 Standby Server: SECONDARY
 Primary 10.1.1.1
 Secondary 10.1.1.2
```

Script:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ cat test.sh 
#! /bin/bash

tr -d '\n' < $1 | sed -r 's/(Node:)/\n\1/g' |\
     perl -lne '
        /^\s+$/ && next;
        /Node:\s+(\w+.*?)\s/ && {$server=$1};
        /Active Server:\s+(\w+.*?)\s/ && {$active=$1};
        /Standby Server:\s+(\w+.*?)\s/ && {$standby=$1};
        /Primary\s+(\w+.*?)\s/ && {$pri=$1};
        /Secondary\s+(\w+.*?)\s/ && {$sec=$1};

        if ( "$active" eq "PRIMARY" ){
            $out="$server,Active,$pri,Standby,$sec";
        }else{
            $out="$server,Active,$sec,Standby,$pri";          
        }
        print $out;
    '
```

Execution:

```
tiago@dell:/tmp$ bash test.sh  file 
server1,Active,192.168.1.2,Standby,192.168.1.1
server2,Active,10.1.1.1,Standby,192.168.1.2
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution as well. In my production file, I have a lot more white spaces which caused most answers here to fail, but this solution resolved that

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk -v RS="" '{$5=tolower($5);sub(".",substr(toupper($5),1,1),$5);$8=tolower($8);sub(".",substr(toupper($8),1,1),$8);print $1,$2"\n"$3,$4,$5,$10"\n",$6,$7,$8,$12}' file
Node: server1
Active Server: Secondary 192.168.1.1
 Standby Server: Primary 192.168.1.2
Node: server2
Active Server: Primary 10.1.1.1
 Standby Server: Secondary 10.1.1.2
```

By sette setting `RS` to nothing, `awk` works with group of line.

Comment: Observe the desired output in the question again.

Comment: Hey Jotne, thanks for the input. However, this doesn't merge the rows based on the keys "Primary" or "Secondary"

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;

my $struct;
local $/ = 'Node: ';


for my $record (<DATA>) {
    next if $record =~ /^Node:/; # skip first
    my ($node, @values) = split /\n\s*/, $record;
    for my $line (@values) { 
        my ($intent, $actual, $ip);
        if ( ($intent, $actual) = $line =~ /(Active|Standby) Server: (.*)$/ ) {
            $struct->{$node}{lc($intent)} = lc($actual);
        }
        elsif ( ($actual, $ip) = $line  =~ /(Primary|Secondary) (.*)$/ ) {
            $struct->{$node}{lc($actual)} = $ip;
        }
    }
}


for my $node (sort keys %$struct) {
    printf "Node: %s\n", $node;
    printf "Active server: %s %s\n", ucfirst $struct->{$node}{active}, $struct->{$node}{$struct->{$node}{active}};
    printf "Standby server: %s %s\n", ucfirst $struct->{$node}{standby}, $struct->{$node}{$struct->{$node}{standby}};
    print "\n";
}

## Desired final output is simpler:
for my $node (sort keys %$struct) {
    say join ',', $node, 'Active', $struct->{$node}{$struct->{$node}{active}}, 'Standby', $struct->{$node}{$struct->{$node}{standby}};
}


__DATA__
Node: server1
 Active Server: SECONDARY
 Standby Server: PRIMARY
 Primary 192.168.1.1
 Secondary 192.168.1.2

 Node: server2
 Active Server: PRIMARY
 Standby Server: SECONDARY
 Primary 10.1.1.1
 Secondary 10.1.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option in awk.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Output processing goes in a function, as it's called from different places
function spew() {
  split(servers[d["active"]], active);
  split(servers[d["standby"]], standby);
  printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",
     d["name"], active[1], active[2], standby[1], standby[2]);
}

# trim unnecessary (leading) whitespace
1 { $1=$1; }

# Store our references
$1=="Active" {
  d["active"]=tolower($3);
}
#
$1=="Standby" {
  d["standby"]=tolower($3);
}

# And store our data
/^ *[A-za-z]+ [0-9.]+$/ {
  servers[tolower($1)]=tolower($0);
}

# Then, if we hit a new record, process the last one.
$1=="Node:" && length(d["name"]) {
  spew();
}

# And if we've just process a record, clear our workspace.
$1=="Node:" {
  delete d;
  delete s;
  d["name"]=$2;
}

# Finally, process the last record.
END {
  spew();
}
```

An advantage of this over some of the other solutions is that it can handle names other than "primary" and "secondary".  The idea is that if you have data like:

```
Node: serverN
Active Server: starfleet
Standby Server: babylon5
starfleet 172.16.0.1
babylon5 172.16.0.2
```

the Active/Standby lines will refer to a record by its index, rather than assuming "Primary" or "Secondary".

I've normalized everything to lower case for easier handling, but you can of course adjust  `tolower()` to suit.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk ' s==0{print;s=1;next;}
      s==1{i=$0;s=2;next;}
      s==2{j=$0;s=3;next;}
      s==3{r1=$0;s=4;next;}
      s==4{r2=$0;
           sub(/SECONDARY/,r2,i);sub(/PRIMARY/,r1,j);
           sub(/SECONDARY/,r2,j);sub(/PRIMARY/,r1,i);
           s=5; print i;print j;next}
      s==5{s=0;print}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
 Node: server1
 Active Server:  Secondary 192.168.1.2
 Standby Server:  Primary 192.168.1.1

 Node: server2
 Active Server:  Primary 10.1.1.1
 Standby Server:  Secondary 10.1.1.2
```

Prints first line of the current input section, stores next four lines in variables, then makes replacements and then print the result. then reads and print the blank line and starts again for next section.